# User's home directory inside another user's home directory?

Tags: linux, home, chown

I'm about to create user and set it's home directory inside another user's home directory - I'm wanderin' is it:

- allowed in *nix world
- possible (I haven't tried in test box yet)
- and does it have any recognized negative aspect?

Case:

`ftp_user1` home dir is `/var/www/vhosts/website/`

I want

`ftp_user2` home dir to be `/var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder/`

*(of course, I'm aware that I will have to chose one user which will be owner of `/var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder/`)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> allowed in *nix world

Practically anything is allowed in the *nix world.

> possible (I haven't tried in test box yet)

Yes, this is possible. When a user is assigned a home directory, that is the directory that the user will `cd` to by default when logging in. You can change `ftp_user2`'s home directory with the `-d` option in `usermod`:

`usermod -d [directory] [ftp_user2]`

In your case, it would look like this: `usermod -d /var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder ftp_user2`

If you still need to create `ftp_user2`, you can assign their home directory while creating them using `useradd`.

`useradd -m -d /var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder -s /bin/bash ftp_user2`

The `-m` option will create the user's home directory if it does not already exist. The `-d` option specifies which home directory is to be assigned to the user. The `-s` option specifies what shell that user will use when logged in. `-s` is not needed, but it is usually good practice to specify a users default shell if that user will be logged in to.

> and does it have any recognized negative aspect?

The only negative aspect I can think of is: If someone decides to delete `ftp_user1` and their home directory, then the home directory for `ftp_user2` will also be deleted.

Comment: I also recommend looking at the man pages for `useradd` and `usermod`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for a user's home directory to be inside another, but it's rare, for good reason. Usually, a user can write to their home directory. If `ftp_user1` can write to `/var/www/vhosts/website/` then `ftp_user1` can rename `/var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder` and can create a new directory by that name, belonging to `ftp_user1` and with contents chosen by `ftp_user1`. For example:

```
mv /var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder /var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder.user2
mkdir /var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder
echo 'cp /bin/sh /tmp/sh.user2; chmod u+s /bin/sh.user2' >/var/www/vhosts/website/subfolder/.profile
```

The next time `ftp_user2` logs in, their `.profile` will run and create a setuid shell, which allows `ftp_user1` (and anyone else) to gain access to the `ftp_user2` account. (Of course this proof-of-concept can be made more robust.)

If `ftp_user1` cannot write to their home directory, then this can be safe, but it is somewhat confusing. There's probably a better way to do whatever drove you to this.